# Plotting a paraboloid

Tags: plotting

I want to plot a paraboloid centered at the origin. I tried

```
 RegionPlot3D[
   (2*x - 1)^2 + (2*y - 1)^2 >= (2*z -1) && 
     (2*x - 1)^2 + (2*y - 1)^2 < (2*z - 1) + 0.1, 
   {z, 0, 1}, {y,0, 1}, {x, 0, 1}]
```

But Mathematica only plots pieces of the image. Could someone explain to me why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use:

```
PlotPoints -> 100
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It's just a matter of telling it to use more `PlotPoints`

```
RegionPlot3D[(2*x - 1)^2 + (2*y - 1)^2 >= (2*z - 1) && (2*x - 1)^2 + (2*y - 1)^2 < (2*z - 1) + 0.1, {z, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {x, 0, 1}, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image]